# fprintf in C doesn't print correctly

Tags: c, tree, printf

I am having a lot of trouble trying to print some tree nodes. The printf function prints everything correctly on the terminal, but fputs and the 2 versions of fprintf just print:

question: fat
question: fat
object: pete
object: pete
question: round
question: round
object: pizza
object: pizza
object: A pangolin
object: A pangolin

$ cat test.txt
question: fat
question: fat
und
golin

Here is the code:

```
void treePrint(struct node *ptr)
{
  if (ptr == NULL)
  printf("ERROR!!!");
else
{    
  char line[1000];
  char filename[] = "test.txt";
  FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w");
  if (!file)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s for writing\n", filename);
    exit(-1);
  }

  if (ptr -> yes_ptr != NULL && ptr -> no_ptr != NULL)
  {
  strcpy(line, "question: ");
  strcat(line, ptr -> questionName);
  strcat(line, "\n");
  printf("%s", line);

  fprintf(file, "%s", line);
  fputs (line, file);
  fprintf(file, "question: %s\n", ptr -> questionName);

  treePrint(ptr -> yes_ptr);
  treePrint(ptr -> no_ptr);
}
else
{
  strcpy(line, "object: ");
  strcat(line, ptr -> objectName);
  strcat(line, "\n");
  printf("%s", line);

  fprintf(file, "%s", line);
  fputs (line, file);
  fprintf(file, "object: %s\n", ptr -> objectName);
}
fclose(file);
}
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't happen. Maybe try the `fprintf`s with `stdout` for output, that way they will output to the console just like `printf`, so you will see.

Comment: Replace `fprintf(stderr, "can't open %s for writing\n", filename)` with `perror(filename)`.  Try it.  You'll like it.

Comment: I did try with stdout, it works perfectly, just like printf. So the problem is with the file?

Comment: Don't put spaces around either `->` or `.` operators; they bind very tightly and the spaces are aconventional (and make your code harder to read).  Make sure your `printf()` operations end with a newline. Many do, but `printf("ERROR!!!");` does not (but should).  The pairs of lines `fprintf(file, "%s", line);` and `fputs (line, file);` appear twice and write the same information twice to the file each time; it would be better to be consistent and use the same call twice in a row, or eliminate the duplication.  Note that neither operation adds a newline at the end.

Comment: You are opening the same file (name) for writing in every recursion, and recurse before closing this file. I can't get my head round what will happen to output buffering when you are using different methods of writing to the file. At the very least, I suggest you open the file before the first call of `treePrint()` and close it afterwards.

Comment: that was the problem! thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening the same file (name) for writing in every recursion, and recurse before closing this file. I can't get my head round what will happen to output buffering when you are using different methods of writing to the file. At the very least, I suggest you open the file before the first call of `treePrint()` and close it afterwards.